# Do explosions destroy stuff?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

*break*: To turn the block into the little floating thing that you can pick up.

*destroy*: To completely obliterate a block, not even leaving a little floating thing.

---

Given those definitions, the question is very simple.  I had read about TNT mining [at another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8310/5029), but when I tried it, it exposed a solitary diamond.  I thought this was odd because I'd never seen one block of diamond ore by itself before, which prompted this question:

**Do explosions destroy stuff?**

Comment: The TNT mining strategy is because less (not sure how much less) ore gets destroyed by TNT than normal (like it's 70% for normal blocks and it might be like 50% for ore). However there are mods that make it 0% ore get destroyed, so it's feasible with that mod.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they can.

> Mining using TNT might be faster than mining by hand but it is impractical for gathering resources; about 70% of the blocks are completely destroyed in the process.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT)

Answer (score 26):

Well, because  <strike>I like to blow stuff up</strike> I'm not the kind of guy to be satisfied by mere Wikis, I did some experimentation:

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

As you can see, the blast broke 9 blocks, yet I only collected 4.

So, **SCIENCE**(!) says that yes, explosions do destroy stuff.