# Minecraft TNT Mining

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got some TNT and a way to set it off, but I'm scared I might destroy precious minerals like diamonds, redstone or gold. Is there a way to set it off, but in a safe way? I know water stops it but then the TNT wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I am tempted to say this is a duplicate of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/do-explosions-destroy-stuff)

Comment: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/18216/10616) could cover it as well.

Comment: It's a good way to get deep. But once on the right level, TNT should not be used. What do you mean by "set it off" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by a safe way you mean one where the TNT wouldn't destroy valuable resources, then no.

TNT is somewhat impractical for mining, because only about 30%-ish of the destroyed resources actually drop as items ([wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT#Mining)). So if you don't want to risk destroying diamonds and such, don't use TNT — at least when you're deep enough for the resources to occur.