# What is the best strategy to mine diamonds in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Diamonds are the best material in the Minecraft. There are many ways to mine diamonds, but which one is the best and most efficient one? If someone can tell me the time it takes, the tools used, the sequence etc, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to mine diamonds in minecraft. The main two ways(which are also the most efficient) are:

1. Strip mining

   Strip mining is a term used in minecraft where the user mines forward below Y 
   12 level (so there would be diamonds since they only spawn below Y 14) and just 
   digs straight forward and mines for as long as he can reach to the left and 
   right every 3 - 4 blocks and if he sees diamonds(or any block he needs) he will mine to it. 
   Here are some example pictures:
   [image: How strip mining looks from above]

   in this picture you can see how strip mining works from above
   [image]

Here is how it would look like from a first person perspective

2. Cave mining

The second best way of mining diamonds is just looking for cave (like a abandoned mine shaft but it could be just any regular old cave) and look for diamonds there. Also check lava pools for diamonds since they commonly spawn there. This is about what it should look like:
[image]

Hopefully this could help you :)