# Why doesn't the diamonds trick work in minecraft 1.17?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, many videos on youtube featured the trick of finding diamonds, by locating a clay patch (preferably symmetrical) and digging 2-6 blocks positive in the Z-axis.
I have tried 6-7 times using this trick, and it never worked, somehow like diamonds are meant to spawn underneath clay patches.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Not everything you see or read on the Internet is always true. Perhaps there's a special seed that the world in your video uses, that has guaranteed diamonds under a specific clay patch?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf There were too many videos on this to be false, although you aren't wrong either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a similar "trick" that works with Lapis.

All of these "tricks" work of mathematical probability - there is no 100% guarantee.
I even had a "trick" where I could guarantee that you would find any ore if you mine out a dirt/gravel patch. None of these are "guaranteed".

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Icj5TNmBUI) also provides the fact that this is not *just* diamonds - it applies to the statistical generation of *any* ore, and even then, this is only applicable to a percentage of seeds, and then there is also the difference between "Swamp Clay" and "River Clay" (I will highlight these):

> SWAMP_CLAY COAL will work reliably on 62.5% of seeds. Z offset 7
> occurs with probability 0.375068 Z offset 4 occurs with probability
> 0.249943 Z offset 14 occurs with probability 0.12498 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.093544 Z offset 1 occurs with probability
> 0.0625
>
> SWAMP_CLAY IRON will work reliably on 68.75% of seeds. Z offset 10
> occurs with probability 0.374945 Z offset 11 occurs with probability
> 0.187534 Z offset 9 occurs with probability 0.124971 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.062561 Z offset 3 occurs with probability 0.062541
>
> SWAMP_CLAY GOLD will work reliably on 75.0% of seeds. Z offset 14
> occurs with probability 0.749988 Z offset 8 occurs with probability
> 0.125011 Z offset 5 occurs with probability 0.093649 Z offset 2 occurs with probability 0.02348 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.005881
>
> SWAMP_CLAY REDSTONE will work reliably on 81.25% of seeds. Z offset 3
> occurs with probability 0.374988 Z offset 4 occurs with probability
> 0.250116 Z offset 1 occurs with probability 0.187387 Z offset 12 occurs with probability 0.062435 Z offset 9 occurs with probability
> 0.04682
>
> **SWAMP_CLAY DIAMOND will work reliably on 87.5% of seeds. Z offset 8
> occurs with probability 0.500088 Z offset 6 occurs with probability
> 0.3749 Z offset 15 occurs with probability 0.062528 Z offset 12 occurs with probability 0.046895 Z offset 10 occurs with probability 0.011681**
>
> SWAMP_CLAY LAPIS will work reliably on 93.75% of seeds. Z offset 11
> occurs with probability 0.500081 Z offset 12 occurs with probability
> 0.249968 Z offset 10 occurs with probability 0.187493 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.031219 Z offset 0 occurs with probability
> 0.023369
>
> RIVER_CLAY COAL will work reliably on 56.25% of seeds. Z offset 1
> occurs with probability 0.249875 Z offset 3 occurs with probability
> 0.187583 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.125 Z offset 0 occurs with probability 0.124946 Z offset 8 occurs with probability 0.093816
>
> RIVER_CLAY IRON will work reliably on 62.5% of seeds. Z offset 7
> occurs with probability 0.375003 Z offset 4 occurs with probability
> 0.250036 Z offset 14 occurs with probability 0.124858 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.093674 Z offset 1 occurs with probability
> 0.062551
>
> RIVER_CLAY GOLD will work reliably on 68.75% of seeds. Z offset 10
> occurs with probability 0.375082 Z offset 11 occurs with probability
> 0.187578 Z offset 9 occurs with probability 0.125048 Z offset 3 occurs with probability 0.062424 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.062411
>
> RIVER_CLAY REDSTONE will work reliably on 75.0% of seeds. Z offset 14
> occurs with probability 0.75008 Z offset 8 occurs with probability
> 0.125033 Z offset 5 occurs with probability 0.093684 Z offset 2 occurs with probability 0.023408 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.005823
>
> **RIVER_CLAY DIAMOND will work reliably on 81.25% of seeds. Z offset 3
> occurs with probability 0.374965 Z offset 4 occurs with probability
> 0.249936 Z offset 1 occurs with probability 0.187548 Z offset 12 occurs with probability 0.062526 Z offset 9 occurs with probability
> 0.046733**
>
> RIVER_CLAY LAPIS will work reliably on 87.5% of seeds. Z offset 8
> occurs with probability 0.499903 Z offset 6 occurs with probability
> 0.375183 Z offset 15 occurs with probability 0.062463 Z offset 12 occurs with probability 0.046953 Z offset 10 occurs with probability
> 0.011689
>
> GRAVEL COAL will work reliably on 50.0% of seeds. Z offset 13 occurs
> with probability 0.499963 Z offset 7 occurs with probability 0.249939
> Z offset 3 occurs with probability 0.187339 Z offset 1 occurs with
> probability 0.047155 Z offset 9 occurs with probability 0.011795
>
> GRAVEL IRON will work reliably on 56.25% of seeds. Z offset 1 occurs
> with probability 0.250058 Z offset 3 occurs with probability 0.187465
> Z offset 0 occurs with probability 0.124965 Z offset 11 occurs with
> probability 0.124954 Z offset 8 occurs with probability 0.093892
>
> GRAVEL GOLD will work reliably on 62.5% of seeds. Z offset 7 occurs
> with probability 0.374988 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.250066
> Z offset 14 occurs with probability 0.124927 Z offset 11 occurs with
> probability 0.09385 Z offset 1 occurs with probability 0.062465
>
> GRAVEL REDSTONE will work reliably on 68.75% of seeds. Z offset 10
> occurs with probability 0.374878 Z offset 11 occurs with probability
> 0.187476 Z offset 9 occurs with probability 0.125008 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.062573 Z offset 3 occurs with probability 0.062502
>
> GRAVEL DIAMOND will work reliably on 75.0% of seeds. Z offset 14
> occurs with probability 0.74992 Z offset 8 occurs with probability
> 0.125093 Z offset 5 occurs with probability 0.093641 Z offset 2 occurs with probability 0.023651 Z offset 11 occurs with probability 0.005766
>
> GRAVEL LAPIS will work reliably on 81.25% of seeds. Z offset 3 occurs
> with probability 0.375061 Z offset 4 occurs with probability 0.250105
> Z offset 1 occurs with probability 0.187341 Z offset 12 occurs with
> probability 0.062501 Z offset 9 occurs with probability 0.046835

Answer (score 0):

This trick only works on about 85% of seeds, and only 70% - 80% of the time. You could be just extremely unlucky, or your seed is just a bad one.

Comment: Well I heard that it works with every seed in 1.17

Comment: @snoop They lied to you and others repeated the lie. Happens all the time. Follow creators that are more honest

Comment: @Navin It's astonishing that this lie has gotten to such a large scale...
Although you may be correct, I find it hard to believe that its just a lie.

Answer (score 0):

The generation for clay and gravel patches are very similar to the generation of diamonds. Diamonds have the generation s + 60009 while the patches have the generation s + 60011, s + 60012 and s + 60013. When you have generation numbers this close in numerical value, the output is strongly correlated. The clay and gravel patch methods only work on 87.5% of seeds and there are an infinite amount of seeds minecraft can generate so maybe that's why. I also tried a bunch of seeds myself until I got one that worked:seed 60009 on 1.16.1. I think this method got patched in 1.18+ so it could also be that you're playing in the wrong version.